# Invalid implicit conversion when creating an array of struct inside a function

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity and I have a struct that takes an array of Traction[], I'm trying to create the array inside a function createItem but I'm getting an invalid implicit conversion.

I have added the entire contract incase if I'm doing something else wrong.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract SupplyChain {
    // Identify the role of an owner
    enum OwnerType {Any, Manufacturer, Ditributor, Retailer, Consumer}

    struct Owner {
        string id; // documentId of a mongo database
        string name;
        OwnerType ownerType;
    }

    // A trasaction is event in the supply chain
    // mostly a change of owner
    struct Transaction {
        string txid; // A generated hash of the transaction
        string previous;
        uint256 timestamp; // Unix timestamp
        bool allowAny; // Anyone can receive/consume the product
        address owner;
        address destination;
        OwnerType destinationType; // Mentions what should be the role of Owner
        string documentId; // documentId that's stored in a mongo database
    }

    struct Item {
        string name;
        uint256 price;
        Transaction[] transactions;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Item) items;
    mapping(address => Owner) owners;

    function createOwner(
        address account,
        string memory documentId,
        string memory name,
        uint8 roleType
    ) public returns (bool) {
        Owner memory owner = Owner(documentId, name, getRoleType(roleType));
        owners[account] = owner;
        return true;
    }

    function getOwner(address account) public returns (Owner memory) {
        Owner memory owner = owners[account];
        return owner;
    }
    
    function getRoleType(uint256 roleType)private returns (OwnerType){
        if(roleType==0){
            return OwnerType.Any;
        }else if(roleType == 1){
            return OwnerType.Manufacturer;
        }else if(roleType == 2){
            return OwnerType.Ditributor;
        }else if(roleType == 3){
            return OwnerType.Retailer;
        }else if(roleType == 4){
            return OwnerType.Consumer;
        }
    }

    function createItem(
        string memory itemName,
        uint256 itemPrice,
        string memory txid,
        uint256 timestamp,
        bool allowAny,
        address ownerId,
        address destination,
        uint256 destinationType,
        string memory documentId
    ) public {
        // Get owner
        Owner memory owner = getOwner(ownerId);
        // Create inital transaction
        Transaction memory transaction = Transaction(
            txid,
            "", // no previous transaction
            timestamp,
            allowAny,
            ownerId,
            destination,
            getRoleType(destinationType),
            documentId
        );
        // ERROR HERE
        // Here I get an error
        // TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct SupplyChain.Transaction memory[1] memory to struct SupplyChain.Transaction memory[] memory requested. Item memory item = Item(itemName, itemPrice, transactionArray);
        Transaction[1] memory transactionArray =  [transaction];
        Item memory item = Item(itemName, itemPrice, transactionArray);
        // If I change the size of the array to dynamic I get the same invalid conversion but on the assignment and not on function call
        
        
        uint256 itemId = 1;
        // Add item to the chain
        items[itemId] = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The types `Transaction[1]` and `Transaction[]` are different:

- Type `Transaction[1]` is a statically-allocated array of `Transaction` objects
- Type `Transaction[]` is a dynamically-allocated array of `Transaction` objects

---

Therefore, you should either change this:

```
Transaction[1] memory transactionArray = [transaction];
```

To this:

```
Transaction[] memory transactionArray = new Transaction[](1);
transactionArray[0] = transaction;
```

Or this:

```
struct Item {
    ...
    Transaction[] transactions;
}
```

To this:

```
struct Item {
    ...
    Transaction[1] transactions;
}
```