# What does this solidity error mean? Thanks

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct storageTank.AddLiquidityParams storage ref to struct LiquidityManagement.AddLiquidityParams memory requested.

```
AddLiquidityParams params = AddLiquidityParams(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7,0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 3, 0x7858E59e0C01EA06Df3aF3D20aC7B0003275D4Bf,34,34,address(this).balance,USDT.balanceOf(address(this)),0,0);

function stakeCombinedLiquidity() public {     
lM.addLiquidity(params);
       require(msg.sender == address(this),'');
        }
```

````
//This is the function I am trying to pass the struct in
``` function addLiquidity(AddLiquidityParams memory params) public
        returns (
            uint128 liquidity,
            uint256 amount0,
            uint256 amount1,
            IUniswapV3Pool pool
        )
    {
        PoolAddress.PoolKey memory poolKey =
            PoolAddress.PoolKey({token0: params.token0, token1: params.token1, fee: params.fee});

        pool = IUniswapV3Pool(PoolAddress.computeAddress(factory, poolKey));

        // compute the liquidity amount
        {
            (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = pool.slot0();
            uint160 sqrtRatioAX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(params.tickLower);
            uint160 sqrtRatioBX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(params.tickUpper);

            liquidity = LiquidityAmounts.getLiquidityForAmounts(
                sqrtPriceX96,
                sqrtRatioAX96,
                sqrtRatioBX96,
                params.amount0Desired,
                params.amount1Desired
            );
        }

        (amount0, amount1) = pool.mint(
            params.recipient,
            params.tickLower,
            params.tickUpper,
            liquidity,
            abi.encode(MintCallbackData({poolKey: poolKey, payer: msg.sender}))
        );

        require(amount0 >= params.amount0Min && amount1 >= params.amount1Min, 'Price slippage check');
    }
````

Comment: Welcome, @AFDS. You need to provide some context to your question by sharing the code so we could help.

Comment: Can you share the code and also check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91173/invalid-implicit-conversion-when-creating-an-array-of-struct-inside-a-function

Comment: Thanks. I already took a look at that. I think my implicit conversion error comes from a data allocation error as I think it needs to be stored in memory but I have it in storage. I'm not sure though. I also have some unneccesary junk seperating some parts so I'm not sure if you want to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Also looking at your other [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102719/constantly-shows-name-has-to-refer-to-a-struct-enum-or-constant-even-though-str) it appears there are several thing going on that complicate thing unnecessarily.

- There's a library `LiquidityManagement` that defines a struct `AddLiquidityParams`, you copied the struct to your contract. Now when the compiler tries to use it they are not the same.
- The `params` is created outside a function, so for the compiler it is in storage. If it is a transient value it is better to keep it in memory.

Probably, it is better to write the function this way

```
function stakeCombinedLiquidity() public {
    LiquidityManagement.AddLiquidityParams memory stakingParam = LiquidityManagement.AddLiquidityParams(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7,0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2, 0.3, 0x7858e59e0c01ea06df3af3d20ac7b0003275d4bf,34,34,address(this).balance,uSDT.balanceOf(address(this)));

    lM.addLiquidity(params);
```